# SQL Agent Job step using Powershell can not find Network Share

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent, powershell

I have a SQL Job step running powershell that cannot find a network drive in one of its steps For brevity, I am calling this server Production, the network share is D:\ on Production and the Job is running on Production. The powershell Job step with issues in running under the SQL Server Agent Service Account.

The first Job step creates an input file on a network share. The second Job step queues an email based on information in the first steps output file. This job is run on server we will call Production. The network share is based the server were the Job is run specifically what we will call here the D:\ drive. When writing the Job step if I use **SELECT-STRING .. -Path "\\network share.."** my job fails it cannot find the Path, but if I use **SELECT-STRING .. -Path "D:..** it runs successfully!

I kept the Job tokens in the code below in case the option for creating a script comes up. I have a solution here, but there is a possiblity I will need to use this script on a different server that does not a have a D:\ and I want to use the network share name for maintainability.

First Job step creates file(run as CmdExec):

```
SQLCmd -S <server> -U <me> -P <Passw0rd> -d <DB> -w 1000 -m-1 -b -i "\\<network share>\Results\20120117_02 Err Message Monitor.sql" -o "\\<network share>\Results\Production.20120117_02.$(ESCAPE_NONE(STRTDT)).$(ESCAPE_NONE(STRTTM)).txt"
```

Second Job step run as Powershell(**specific problem line listed below**)

```
$sel = SELECT-STRING "Nothing to do" -path "\\<network share>\Results\Production.20120117_02.$(ESCAPE_NONE(STRTDT)).$(ESCAPE_NONE(STRTTM)).txt"
if ($sel -eq $null) {
    Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;
EXEC DBATools.dbo.s_DBAEmailINS
    @ToList = 'My@email.com',
    @Subject = '(Prod) Message Monitor',
    @AttachmentList = '\\<network share>\Results\Production.20120117_02.$(ESCAPE_NONE(STRTDT)).$(ESCAPE_NONE(STRTTM)).txt';"
}
else {
    Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;
EXEC DBATools.dbo.s_DBAEmailINS
    @ToList = 'Me@email.com',
    @Subject = 'Nothing to do (Prod) Message Monitor',
    @AttachmentList = '\\<network share\Results\Production.20120117_02.$(ESCAPE_NONE(STRTDT)).$(ESCAPE_NONE(STRTTM)).txt';"
}
```

**Problem is here**

```
$sel = SELECT-STRING "Nothing to do" -path "\\<network share>\Results\Production.20120117_02.$(ESCAPE_NONE(STRTDT)).$(ESCAPE_NONE(STRTTM)).txt"
```

This works:

```
$sel = SELECT-STRING "Nothing to do" -path "D:\Results\Production.20120117_02.$(ESCAPE_NONE(STRTDT)).$(ESCAPE_NONE(STRTTM)).txt"
if ($sel -eq $null) {
    Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;
EXEC DBATools.dbo.s_DBAEmailINS
    @ToList = 'My@email.com',
    @Subject = '(Prod) Message Monitor',
    @AttachmentList = '\\<network share>\Results\Production.20120117_02.$(ESCAPE_NONE(STRTDT)).$(ESCAPE_NONE(STRTTM)).txt';"
}
else {
    Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;
EXEC DBATools.dbo.s_DBAEmailINS
    @ToList = 'Me@email.com',
    @Subject = 'Nothing to do (Prod) Message Monitor',
    @AttachmentList = '\\<network share\Results\Production.20120117_02.$(ESCAPE_NONE(STRTDT)).$(ESCAPE_NONE(STRTTM)).txt';"
}
```

There are no Proxy accounts.

How can I get my **-Path** to access a network share in this Job?

Comment: D:\ is going to be a mapped drive *for a specific user*. You need to make sure that the account that is trying to access \\network share\ actually has access. You can figure out who it is by running whoami from that job.

Comment: Make sure your service account is an admin on the box.

Comment: @Aaron, he said that the D:\ worked, the network path did not.  Vic, Try putting a C:\ on it's own line in the script before accessing drive/network resources.  I've found that the PowerShell built into SQL Server mis-interprets the file system access unless I put that first.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I did not think of that, that is something I may need that in the future. Sadly, the account displayed from "whoami" is in a group that has access to that share.

Comment: @JonathanFite do you mean Set-Location C:\?

Comment: @JonathanFite he said that D:\ worked on one machine but it was clearly a mapped drive so would not be eligible on other machines or even for other users on this machine.

Comment: I tried Set-Location C:\ at the top of my script right before $sel and it failed also. But I am trying to acess the shared subfolder within D:\ specifically D:\Results or through the share \\<network share>\Results\... the account from whoami has full control over this file. Could Powershell think its on a different computer because its a share?

Comment: PowerShell job steps don't use the full PowerShell shell, so some functionality won't work. I don't know if that's the answer here, but as a general rule, I prefer to use a cmdexec job step and call PowerShell.exe

Comment: @AMtwo I had thought I heard in a video that the powershell through SQL Server was just calling the Powershell.exe but I believe that you are correct., That also explains to me why people call Powershell.exe through cmdexec jobs. Thank you!

Comment: SQL Agent PowerShell job steps actually use sqlps.exe, not PowerShell.exe.

Comment: @vicWork [reference what version of PowerShell you are under with SQL Agent PS step.](http://www.sqlhammer.com/running-powershell-in-a-sql-agent-job/)

Answer (score 3):

I cannot explain why this is the answer but it is:

```
$sel = SELECT-STRING "Nothing to do" -path "D:\Results\Production.20120117_02.$(ESCAPE_NONE(STRTDT)).$(ESCAPE_NONE(STRTTM)).txt"
```

Changed to:

```
New-PSDrive -Name "P" -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "\\<network share\Results"
$sel = SELECT-STRING "Nothing to do" -path "P:\Ad-hoc\Results\20120117_02\Production.20120117_02.$(ESCAPE_NONE(STRTDT)).$(ESCAPE_NONE(STRTTM)).txt"
```

Runs successful! There were NO permission changes but I guess powershell needs a [temporary with PS-Drive] local path to run. Again ZERO permission changes and if I were to replace the "P:\" with the "\\network share\Results" it would fail.

This is what I needed. The network share name will not be changing but a drive letter on the server can change so this is maintainable for me and reusable in my other Jobs.